# Can't start rabbitmq-server

Tags: services, openstack

While trying to start the `rabbitmq-server start`, I'm getting an error. I did some research and found that this issue could be because of permissions. So I tried the "sudo service rabbitmq-server start" command, the result was the same...

## ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Starting message broker rabbitmq-server                                  
 FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_\{log, _err\}
```

## LOGS

```
rabbitmqctl list_permissions -p openstack
Listing permissions in vhost "openstack" ...
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@controller: nodedown
```

Comment: Server.log 
2015-06-10 17:53:54.628 4252 INFO neutron.openstack.common.rpc.common [-] Reconnecting to AMQP server on controller:5672
2015-06-10 17:53:57.636 4252 ERROR neutron.openstack.common.rpc.common [-] AMQP server on controller:5672 is unreachable: Socket closed. Trying again in 30 seconds.